# Problems with Div Positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a div id css called frontwidth which holds 1 img 1 title and 1 text.

When I do a second or third frontwidth its laying behind themselves instead of going underneath and underneath.

Comment: An id is meant to be unique.  If you have several items you want to style the same way, use a class.

Comment: You should add a code sample when asking a question like this.

Comment: @MikeEast - he's got one, see the URL in the post.

Comment: Wow, that's.. a unique approach? You have *far* too much `position: absolute` and `position: relative`. I just fixed this in Firebug, but it's going to take a few minutes to write an answer, the amount of rules I had to toggle and add.

Comment: Good point, i've sorted that one but still doesn't sort my problem lol thanks for that though

Comment: I suggest you read up on inline and block elements and also the use of relative and absolute positioning.  If you're not familiar with the CSS box model, check that out for good measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:

> Wow, that's.. a unique approach? You
>   have far too much `position: absolute`
>   and `position: relative`. I just fixed
>   this in Firebug, but it's going to
>   take a few minutes to write an answer,
>   the amount of rules I had to toggle
>   and add.

Remove the `position` rule from each of these elements:

- `#mainbody`.
- `#frontwidth`.
- `#titlesbig`.
- `#greyline`.
- `#homepageimage`.
- `#titlesmedium`.
- `#homepagetext`.
- Hope I didn't forget any :D

With the exception of `mainbody`, you're using each of those elements multiple times.

So, change to using a `class` instead.

For example, in your HTML, change to:

```
<div class="frontwidth">
```

And in your CSS, change to:

```
.frontwidth {

}
```

Now we can get to laying out those elements as you want them:

- On `.homepageimage`, add `float: left`.
- On `.frontwidth`, add `overflow: hidden` (to [*clear the floats*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)).
- On `.titlesmedium` and `.homepagetext` add `margin-left: 340px`.

Comment: Spot on perfect.... I can never get my head round divs...

Answer (score 2):

You have positioned all of the content inside the `frontwidth` divs absolute. Absolute positioning takes elements out of the flow and all other elements are positioned as if they weren't there.

The best solution would be not to use `position: absolute` (which is a "last resort" thing to use usually anyway).  Instead float the image left and give the title and text a left margin.

Some more advice:

- Many of your images are lacking `alt` attributes.
- Your source code is a big `div` soup. "Table-less layout" doesn't mean "only use `div`s". Don't wrap things in `div`s for the heck of it. For example it's unnecessary to wrap each image in a div. You can apply the style directly to the images. And use meaningfull elements like `h1`, `h2`, etc. for headlines, `p` for text paragraphs, `ul` and `li` for lists (menues), etc. `div`s are "last resort" thing, too. Only use them if no other HTML element is suitable.

Comment: Wrapping an image in a plain div not only adds unneeded structure to the page, it changes the layout.  An image is an inline element, but wrap it in a div and now both act like block elements.

Comment: @thritydot: Can advice be sage if the one giving it didn't know what "sage" means?

Comment: You typoed my name, so I didn't get a comment notification. Well, you know what it means now :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your usage of position: absolute and position: relative.

If you remove those from the css, the  no longer stacks on top of each other.
try removing those and then adjusting the html

Comment: IS it best to position them with left: and right: then ?

Comment: How do i get the Blah Blah to sit beside the picture then without using absolute ?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the layout sorts itself out if you remove `position: absolute` from the homepageimage, titlesmedium and homepagetext classes.  The various `position: relative` elements aren't causing problems because they don't have any references to top, bottom, left or right - essentially, they aren't changing the layout at all.

To make one element sit next to another, you can use float.  For instance, float the image left and then float the title left.  This will place the title next to the image.  Afterwards, be sure to use clear to start flowing elements as normal again.  Alternately, get rid of all the extra divs - you're changing the layout by adding lots of extra elements.  For wrapping and styling an inline element, consider a `<span>` tag instead.